# How to compare new project to existing Gitlab repo

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a CMS based project that I was keeping in sync by directly updating a test site (copying files) and then, after testing, copying those files to the production site.  It was klunky and subject to error.  So, I added a Gitlab repo so I could more efficiently maintain the sites.  I copied the production files over to the repo and then cloned the repo to my development machine.  I am now tracking and committing my changes from my development machine to the Gitlab repo.

My issue is that I now want to be able to pull changes from the Gitlab repo into the test and production environments using git.  But I don't know how to get those environments "aware" of changes in the Gitlab repo without starting with a "clone" of the repo.  I just want to add git control to each environment  and then begin pulling and merging those changes.

Is there a way to initialize each environment without a clone that will make it possible to grab changes from the repo?

I added git to the test environment (remote server) using the git init command to create an empty local repo and then set the origin and pulled from the repo.  But I am not sure that is the correct step.  If so, how do I then determine what is different from the "pull" and the local files?  That is where I am stuck.

My hope is that I can compare the differences between the local files and those pulled from the repo and then merge the few files that I know are different.  Then, going forward all I will need to do is to pull in the changes each time I have pushed my dev changes to the repo.  Right now my confusion is how to compare and sync the changes since there wasn't a clone to set the baseline on the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cli or any git-ui-tool to manage your repository.
Basically it is good to know about a git-workflow: https://de.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows
Work with branches. Check out a new branch for development with good name e.g. 'feature/my_awesome_development'.
After you have finished your work, merge this with the master and push the master to gitlab. Delete 'feature/my_awesome_development' because it's done. Your next branch can be 'fix/my_awesome_development_didnt_work' ;)

I suggest to have a further branch called 'production'. This is only checked out on your server in productive environment.
All you have to do by now is going into the directory of your sources, the git-branch 'production' and pull from master with 'git pull origin master' from command line. The gitlab-master sources will be pulled into your working branch.

Comment: Thanks.  I am using the cli.  I have different branches in the repo.   I still don't quite understand how to get the test server instance updated from the Gitlab repo because the test instance was never cloned from the repo. It was originally copied from the production instance to test, not cloned.  Now I need to sync this test instance, which has never been "connected" to the Gitlab repo.  I understand the git-workflow I just can't find instructions how to make a copied, uncloned  instance part of that workflow without first cloning the repo.

Comment: I guess git depends on git. You might think about a solution for syncing files like rsync or bigger tools. If you want to look for differences in these files I recommend e.g "diff" https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diff-command-linux-examples/

Comment: Not sure if I took the correct approach but I added a local repo with git init.  Added the local files with git add .  and then defined the remote repository and ran git pull from that repository.  

The results were OK.  I think I ended up replacing the whole instance with the pull (not sure) but  I think I got the updates I needed and hopefully will only get changed files in the future.  Probably the same as a git clone that I was trying to avoid....

Comment: I guess this was right. "git pull" is a "git fetch & git merge". Git would alert you in case there are uncommitted changes on your local branch.